# Pycharm custom region in HTML code for code folding like C# region syntax

Tags: pycharm, code-folding

We have *C#-like region syntax* aka. **custom code folding** [supported in Pycharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/code-folding.html#using_folding_comments) which is currently so lovely.

Though only support in .py code; how can we get it also work in template and/or .html code?

The below syntax not working.

```
{#region#} ... {#endregion#}

<!--region--> ... <!--endregion-->
```

p.s.
Seem to have nothing helpful form a google search on this [01](http://Pycharm%20custom%20region%20in%20HTML%20code%20for%20code%20folding%20like%20C#%20region%20syntax) [02](https://www.google.com.vn/#q=PyCharm+syntax+to+have+a+Jinja+%60custom+code+folding%2Fregion%60+in+HTML+file).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38630378/248616), if it is safe to use, we may make use of **condition-in-comment syntax** for custom region in HTML in PyCharm.

```
<!--YOUR COMMENT GOES HERE--><!--[]>
  YOUR HTML GOES HERE
<![]-->
```

Comment: Though this syntax will hide/disable all HTML code if-any defined in the block