# Will this cause error for IE when using <!--[]>HTML GOES HERE<![]-->?

Tags: html, internet-explorer

I notice that we can use [condition-in-comment for IE browsers](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html) and in some IDE such as [PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) we have the code folding for it as the attached snapshot.

[image]

So I wonder if I would **cause any error for IE** when using the syntax to create *collapsible code-region* as below snippet

```
<!--YOUR COMMENT GOES HERE--><!--[]>
  <script src="someSource"></script>
<![]-->
```

Comment: Well you haven't actually closed the comment in the one line. `<!--[some comment goes here]-->`.

Comment: @Paul and Quentin Thanks for your comments. I've fixed it.